# Google Maps project in Codename One will not build

Tags: java, android, google-maps, netbeans, codenameone

I am trying to build a Google Maps test application in Codename One using NetBeans. I have followed all of the directions on the CodenameOne site for this (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/mapping-natively.html), however when I try to send the Android build to their servers for testing, I get an error.

The only file I have edited in this project is the main Java file where I just copied the code from the Codename One website above and changed the package name and class name to run correctly.

Also, when I run this on the emulator it appears to work. Did I miss something, or is there something I can do to make this work?

The error is as follows:

- What went wrong:
  Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build7941379349764370420xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- Try:
  Run with --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build7941379349764370420xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
  at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getPackageFromManifest(VariantConfiguration.java:999)
  at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getOriginalApplicationId(VariantConfiguration.java:780)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy:167)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig_Decorated.getBuildConfigPackageName(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:458)
  at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:166)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:456)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator.validate(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:277)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the package name you need to change it everywhere to match. That is you need to open the `codenameone_settings.properties` and change that to match your new package name everywhere.